# UITableViewCell with image background, ignoring touches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi have setup a `UITableViewCell` from a nib file and everything is working as expected. However I decided it would be nice to add a `UIImageView` as a background to make the cell a bit more interesting, the only problem is that the new `UIImageView` is now stopping touches getting to the underlying `UITableViewCell` (i.e. the cells do not turn blue when you tap them). What do I need to set on the UIImageView to allow it to pass-through touches?

**EDIT:**
I am not sure if this is the correct way but I created a a new "Highlighted" version of my image background and added it to the `UIImageView` using the "Highlighted" pulldown.

cheers Gary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the image to the tableview cells background view, not its content view.